# How to hide one unknown menu in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There is one weird menu which i need to get rid of. Even when I split vscode environment into more pages (two,three...) it creates this menu for every page area. I have not even find what is the name of this menu, much less how to hide it. Please, does anyone at least know what is the name of this menu?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those are source control buttons, try to uncheck some of these.

[image]

Comment: I cannot find this menu at all